# Multiplicative Inverse of Modulo n is UNIQUE

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove this: $x,b,n\in \mathbb{Z}, \space xb\;(\mod{n}\;) = 1 \implies   $ b is unique.

I have tried by using proof by contradiction. That is, assume there are integers $b,c$ where the above first condition is satisfied. Then we know that $xb \equiv xc\equiv 1 \;(\mod{n}\;)$ meaning $n|(x(b-c))$ and $xb = xc + k_1n, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $xb + k_2n = 1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $xc + k_3n = 1, k_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$. That's all I got. I don't know how to proceed. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\gcd(x,n)=1$ and $n| x(b-c)\implies n|(b-c)\iff b\equiv c\pmod n$

Comment: @JackNicholson, $$4\equiv1,7\equiv1\pmod3$$   Congruent values are considered as same in modular arithmetic

Comment: Oh my goodness I finally get it now thanks!

Comment: I'm new to finite field arithmetic, can you please explain to me why $n$ divides $b-c$ ?

Comment: @VivekanandV, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thankyou very much !!!

Answer (score 10):

Assume $xb\equiv xc\equiv1\pmod n$. Then:
\begin{align}
b&\equiv 1b\\
&\equiv xcb\\
&\equiv xbc\\
&\equiv1c\\
&\equiv c\pmod n
\end{align}