# How to prove the uniqueness of multiplicative inverse modulo n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1443111/482283), I have learned

[image]

However, I can't figure out why can it replace $1$ with $xc$, there is no such property [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: Um, if $M\equiv N\mod n $ then $Mv\equiv Nv\mod n $ for all $v $.  That's a basic property of multiplication.  So as $xc \equiv 1\mod n $  we know $xcb\equiv 1b\mod n $.  The thing that makes this specific to *1*, is $1b=b$.  If we had $xc=xb=2\mod n$ we could conclude $2b\equiv xcb\equiv 2c\mod n $ but we could not conclude $b=c\mod n$.

Comment: @fleabloodI also agree $xc≡1\mod n\ \ \ \ \ \ xb≡1\mod n \ \ \ \ \ \ $           we know   $ xcb≡1b\mod \ \ \ \ n$ but it can't explain $xcb \equiv (xc)b \equiv (1)b \mod n$

Comment: Of course it can!!! $M\equiv N \mod n \implies Mv \equiv Nv \mod n$.  So let M = 1, N = xc and v= b.  So $1*b \equiv xcb \mod n$.  Then let M= xb; N=1 and v = c So $xbc \equiv 1*c$.  $1*b = b$ and $xcb = xbc$ and $1*c=c$  and $A\equiv B \mod n; A=C; B=D\implies C\equiv D \mod n$ take care of the rest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

$1*b \equiv 1*b \mod n$.  (Reflexivity)

$1*b = b$. (Basic algebra: Multiplicative identity)

$b \equiv 1*b \mod n$.  (Meaning of equality.  $1*b$ and $b$ are the same thing.)

$xc \equiv 1 \mod n$ (Given)

$(xc)*b \equiv (1)*b \mod n$.  ($ka \equiv kb \mod n$)

$(xc)*b = xcb = xbc=(xb)c;$ (Basic algebra: associativity and commutivity of multiplication.)

$(xb)c \equiv b \mod n$. (Meaning of equality: $(xb)*c = (xc)*b$ and $b=(1)*b$ and we already kknow $(xc)*b \equiv (1)*b \mod n$.)

$xb \equiv 1 \mod n$.  (Given)

$(xb)c \equiv (1)c$ ($ka \equiv kb \mod n$)

$1*c = c$.  (Basic algebra: multiplicative identity)

$(xb)c \equiv c \mod n$. (Meaning of equality)

$b \equiv (xb)c \mod n$. (Symmetry: $a \equiv b \mod n \implies b \equiv a \mod n$)

$(xb)c \equiv c \mod n$. (Just repeating the line above the last one again.)

$b \equiv c \mod n$ (Transitivity: $a \equiv b \mod n; b\equiv c \mod n\implies a \equiv c \mod n$.

Comment: That's the answer I want!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The property you are using is on the webpage linked. It is in the second set of bullet points. It reads:

If $a \equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $k$ is an integer, then $ka\equiv kb\pmod{n}$.

From $1\equiv xc \pmod{n}$ we can conclude $1b \equiv xcb \pmod{n}$.

Comment: but how to explain $xbc \equiv 1c$, there is no property about division.

Comment: There's no property for division.  But there sire as heck is one for multiplicTion.  And for 1, multiplication is enough.

Comment: It would not work for a=b=k mod n for any k except 1.

Comment: xb=1 mod n and xc=1 mod n so b=(1)b=(xc)b=(xb)c=(1)c= c mod n.  No division was done at all.  Just substitution.

Comment: @fleablood thanks! But the key is I didn't find property about **substitution**. If operator $=$, I'm sure about substitution, however, for $\equiv mod$, I'm confused about **substitution**.

Comment: You are confused that if $a = b$ and $a \equiv c \mod n$ that $b \equiv c\mod n$???????

Comment: Substitution *ALWAYS* works for *EVERYTHING*.  $A=C$ means that $A$ and $C$ are the exact same thing.  So if I say $A$ can be tossed into a gamflanger with a torqboop factor of Quince resulting in $57$.  Then will have to be true that $C$ can be tossed into a gamflanger with a torqboop factor of Quince resulting in $57$.  Because $A$ and $C$ are the same thing.