# Prove that $a\equiv 0 $ $(mod$ $p)$ given $\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $p$ is prime and $gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

That is prove that the numerator of $\sum^{p-1}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k^2}$ expressed in lowest terms is divisible by $p$ where $p$ is prime.

I have tried to express the numerator but am not having much luck reducing it and I cannot find much online that is helpful here. Any hints/help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: GCD $ (a,b)=0?$

Comment: @Labbhattacharjee fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\dfrac1{k^2}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}r^2\pmod p$$

as $(k,p)=1$ for $1\le k<p,$ there exists a unique $r,1\le r<p$ such that $kr\equiv1\pmod p$

See also: [Multiplicative Inverse of Modulo n is UNIQUE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443110/multiplicative-inverse-of-modulo-n-is-unique)

Comment: Because each element has a unique inverse mod p? I think I will be able to get it now, thanks!

Comment: @Rick, Thanks for the rectification